# Relacionamento entre tabelas n para n

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou criando um pequeno projeto e estou com uma dúvida.

Vamos supor que eu tenha um determinados tipos de cafés, esses cafés podem ser servidos em mais de dois tamanhos de xícaras. Como o relacionamento entre as tabelas são de **n para n**, temos as seguintes tabelas:

Os comando SQL ficam:

```
create table cafes (id_cafe int auto_increment not null, nome_cafe varchar(30) not null,
primary key (id_cafe));

create table xicara (id_xicara int auto_increment not null, nome_xicara varchar(30) not null,
primary key (id_xicara));

create table xicara_cafe (id_cafe int, id_xicara int,
primary key (id_cafe, id_xicara));

alter table xicara_cafe foreign key (id_cafe) references cafes(id_cafe);

alter table xicara_cafe foreign key (id_xicara) references xicara(id_xicara);
```

Acontece que está dando erro exatamente no relacionamento entre as tabelas. Queria a dica para esse impasse.

Comment: `alter table ... ADD foreign key`

Answer (score 1):

Formalizando a resposta (citada no comentário do Havenard), faltou o `ADD` antes do comando `foreign key`:

```
alter table xicara_cafe add foreign key (id_cafe) references cafes(id_cafe);

alter table xicara_cafe add foreign key (id_xicara) references xicara(id_xicara);
```

Você pode ainda fazer diretamente pela criação da tabela:

```
create table xicara_cafe (id_cafe int, id_xicara int,
primary key (id_cafe, id_xicara),
foreign key(id_cafe) references cafes(id_cafe),
foreign key(id_xicara) references xicara(id_xicara));
```

Documentação do [`SQL FOREIGN KEY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) (em inglês).